# Setting a default selected value into a dropdown list

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to set a default value selected on the list generated from the viewbag. The default selected item on the list is the first item(it is an empty item ""). Anyone that could help.
Code in .cshtml file :
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TimeZoneId, "Generic_DropDownList", new { Items = ViewBag.TimeZones, InputClass = "InvisibleField", HideFormUnit = true, HideLabel = true })

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a default selected value,try to use the following code:

```
<select asp-for="TimeZoneId">
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.TimeZones)
    {
        <option>Generic_DropDownList</option>
        if (item.Value == "{Value}")
        {          
            <option value=@item.Value selected>@item.Text</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value=@item.Value>@item.Text</option>
        }
    }

</select>
```

Comment: Should i use this code, instead of the one that i posted , or should i modify it ?

Comment: You need to set `item.Value` with `item.Value == "{Value}"` ,and change `{Value}` to the value what you want to set it as the slected value.

Comment: I have tried it just you said but i don't see any difference. Im attaching the total div, please can you modify it ? 
<div class="FormGrid FormGrid100 Mobile100">
                    <label for="TimeZoneId">@RM["UserTimeZone"] *</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TimeZoneId, "Generic_DropDownList", new { Items = ViewBag.TimeZones, InputClass = "InvisibleField", HideFormUnit = true, HideLabel = true })
                </div>

Comment: Which value you want to select?